# Coordinates from the expo-location are not accurate

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation, android-gps

I have a big problem with [expo-location](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/) package accuracy.
Based on this example https://github.com/byCedric/office-marathon I was trying to write an app tracking my car's position during drive.
Unfortunately, location coordinates are not accurate. From time to time coordinates show the wrong point hundreds of meters from my real position. I tried to fix it by including only coordinates with the best 'accuracy' parameter  (accuracy < 10), however, it doesn't matter as still the coordinates can be very inaccurate.
I have all the required permissions on my Android device, and I have set accuracy as "Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation".
I tried to change some settings regarding `timaInterval` and `distanceInterval`, but without any positive effect.

Could you tell me if I can do anything with that? Maybe it is completely normal behavior and in order to get more accurate coordinates I have to use a pay solution, do you have any knowledge about it?